# Experimental proof of length elongation due to gravitational field?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime

In general relativity we see that length around a massive object is elongated due to its effect on the geometry of spacetime which elongates the length due to stretched space time.
Is there any experiment to prove this?
Or is it still only theoretical?

Comment: *Do* we see this?

Answer (score 0):

> In general relativity we see that length around a massive object is elongated due to its effect on the geometry of spacetime which elongates the length due to stretched space time.

You're starting from a false premise. There is no such effect. GR describes gravity as curvature of spacetime, not stretching of spacetime.

Comment: I think the OP may be confusing what is usually referred to as "sphagettification" with stretching of spacetime

Comment: "Curving", "stretching" is there a real difference. Conceptually, it is sometime easier to explain the mathematical concept of curvature, by phrasing it in terms of spacetime being locally stretched and compressed. This avoids the common layman's misconception that spacetime would have to be embedded in something else in order to be curved.

Answer (score 0):

The question may refer to two different issues: tidal force on a macroscopic object and proper length.

Tidal force
In a spacetime surrounding a massive object, two different points of a macroscopic object are subjected to the tidal force given by the curvature of the geometry. That implies a radial stretch and a transverse compression. This is known as spaghettification. This can be measured on earth, however due to the mass of the earth the magnitude is negligible.

Proper length
The proper length is the physical length along a radial direction for a slice of the spacetime at constant time coordinate. It becomes progressively longer than the radial coordinate distance as you approach the massive object. In case of a blackhole it tends to infinity as you come close to the horizon. That is why, a far away observer will never see an infalling object to reach the horizon.